# Slide left and right menu for mobile devices

Tags: jquery, css, menu, uislider

just wondering if anybody has come accross a tutorial or a website that explains how you can achieve this sort of responsive menu navigation, where on mobiles you can scroll left and right between menus. As seen on the AIDS.GOV website http://www.aids.gov/.

I am not just being lazy by posting this on here, I have spent all morning looking and can only find a facebook style slide in menu tutorials.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe if you use http://jquerymobile.com/ for that issue in particular. In the aids web page they use http://swipejs.com/